# Expectation of random variable with density function $\frac{1}{18}(6-x), 0\leq x\leq 6$.

Tags: probability, expectation, variance

> Consider the random variable  $X$  with the following probability density function
>   $$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{18}(6-x), & 0\leq x\leq 6\\
> 0,& \text{otherwise.}
> \end{cases}$$
>   (a) Compute $E(X)$.
>   (b) Compute $\operatorname{Var}(X)$.

I'm not sure what approach I should be using to get this answer. What is the method to get the final solutions for this answer?

For (b) I did

$\int^6_0\frac{1x^2}{18}(6-x)dx-6$ and plugged it into my calculator to get $0$ where did I got wrong?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to accurately present your problem.

Comment: @Kate.K, in your edit you subtract the $\text{E}(X^2)$ from itself. We have that $\text{E}(X^2) = 6$, and $\text{E}(X) = 2$. Remember $\text{Var}(X) = \text{E}(X^2) - [\text{E}(X)]^2$. Notice the distinction between the two terms in the expression for variance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These formulas will be useful. However, try adjusting the limits of $\text{E}(X)$ to better suit your PDF.

$$\text{E}(X) = \int_{\infty}^{- \infty} xf(x) dx$$

$$\text{Var}(X) = \text{E}(X^2) - [\text{E}(X)]^2$$

As a little side note, the $\text{E}(X)$ notation for the expected value is really just an instruction to multiply the the  PDF by $x$, and integrate
over all values of the random variable. The $\text{E}(X^2)$ notation is similar, except we just use $x^2$ instead.

Comment: Okay, I used this approach and got a right but b wrong. I got a=2 and b=0

Comment: I'll be posting my working for b

Comment: Good idea :) @Kate.K

Comment: Just added the update

Comment: I've added my response as a comment to your question. Let me know if you still need some clarification.